# How to disabled date in v-calendar?

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js, vcalendar

I just create a full calendar with vuetify using v-calendar based on [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars)
But i have trouble to disabled date. Example: " i want to disable all sunday."
Any idea?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite tricky, though if you want to disable the "day" button in calendar monthly view, you can use [`day-label`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#day-label) slot.

```
<template #day-label="{ date }">
  <v-btn
    fab
    small
    :disabled="isSunday(date)"
  >
    <span v-text="day" />
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

@bill.gates answer is correct. You should be able to disable all sundays with this prop:

```
:disabled-dates="{ weekdays: [1] }"
```

[1] stands for sunday as it is the first day of the week. Maybe you should review your code and remove the other props to check if there is one causing conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
:disabled-dates='{ weekdays: [1, 7] }'
```

Was a correct answer, but not anymore.
The way to do it now is:

```
disabledDates: {
  repeat: {
    weekdays: [1, 7]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yea with this prop:

```
:disabled-dates='{ weekdays: [1, 7] }'
```

This should for example disable saturday and sunday.

Comment: I already try this code, but didn't work. it doesn't disabled saturday and sunday.

Comment: @pito could you show me a code / image how you tried it and did you check console for errors

Comment: This is the code : `<v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="focus"
          color="primary"
          :events="events"
          :event-color="getEventColor"
          :type="type"
          :disabled-dates="{ weekdays: [1, 7] }"
          @click:event="showEvent"
          @click:more="viewDay"
          @click:date="viewDay"
          @change="updateRange"
        ></v-calendar>` , and no error in console